# How to get P tags found in div tags with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium

I want to get all of the P tags that is found inside the div tag I just want to get the size so I've tried this line of code

`driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='googleresults']/div/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/div")).size()`

I got this xpath from fireBug but this line code gives me 0

```
<document>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="googleresults">
<div class="tab-container">
<!-- Please enter html code below. -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"/>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<!--tro2-->
<div>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
<p class="g">
<br/>
</div>
<center>
<span class="p">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Comment: Your xpath needs to include the p tag at the end. Right now it is looking for div tag. Can u include the html in the post?

Comment: I have tried to put /p[1] at the end of the xpath, but didn't work either.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It Turned out that this div in found inside an iframe so I needed to set the focus on the iframe first and then use this line. It is now working.

the code for focusing on the iframe is below:
`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeID")));`

Answer (score 3):

Best way to get values of any tag is find by tag name, in your case it should be like this:

```
List<WebElement> element=driver.findElements(By.tagName("p")); 
System.out.println(element.size());
```

Comment: If you Like the answer then, please give me up rating. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use following XPath-

`//div//p[@class='g']` to get all `<p>` tags

and this code will provide how may `<p>` tags are there

```
    List<WebElement> element=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div//p[@class='g']"));
    System.out.println(element.size());
```

Comment: this div is included in two other divs, can this cause a problem ?

Comment: I hope it should work, at my end I'm getting the expected result. can you show your code snippet ?

Comment: It Turned out that this div in found inside an iframe so I needed to set the focus on the iframe first and then use this line. It is now working.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to hear :) happy coding